# Keras 'cross section' model with time trend

Tags: keras, time-series

**Problem:** I have a problem in which cross-sectional features (X) explain a continuous outcome (y). In addition, there is a linear time trend (t) in the data.

Using OLS, such a model would write: $y = b_0 + b_1 X + b_2 t + u$. Here, $b_1$ captures the cross sectional effects attributable to X and $b_2$ captures the time trend.

I would like to implement the logic of the OLS model in a Keras NN context.

I have tried "normal" `Sequential()` models with `Dense()` layers, but these model types do not fit the data very well. In fact, the Keras `Sequential()` model does not even beat a simple OLS model in terms of MAE.

I suspect that the `Sequential()` model architecture is not fit to deal with the linear time trend in my data.

I had a look at `LSTM()` models, but it seems that these models are mostly used to deal with autoregressive processes (at least this is what I could find online).

**Question:** What would be a good Keras model architecture to deal with a linear time trend as described above?

Can someone point me to some instructive resources?